# Collimated lens for a ir led

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, lenses

I've read, read and read but found no answer to my interrogations. I want to collimate a 3mm IR LED 890 nm (I can use many LED angles) and I have no idea how to calculate the distance of the lens or the 2 lenses from the IR LED and which thickness of those lens (is it important the thickness)? Some sites say that one should use an aspheric lens; others suggest 2 lenses: a plano-convex and a plano-concave back to back with the plano-convex surface in front of the LED with it back against the second lens, the plano-concave lens; with both lens curves should be oriented on the LED side.

So, the typical app is: I want to collimate a IR LED (my first choice is a $\pm 3$ degree half intensity IR LED) in a point of max 5 mm. Any help please I'm so confused!!!!

Can we approximate a lens without using complex formulas?

Thank you!
-Ronny

Answer (score -1):

If you are finding plano convex and plano concave lenses as solutions, I would guess you are looking at sites for far infrared like the 10.6 um wavelength CO2 lasers emit. These lasers need exotic materials for lenses, like ZnSe. An aspherical lense is a very expensive solution you would use if you want a really good beam quality.

Your wavelength is near IR, just beyond the visible. You will use ordinary glass lenses. You may want to look up indices of refraction at 890 nm to find how the focal length of the lenses will be affected by your wavelength.

You probably can find inexpensive lenses at companies like Melles Griot. Their web sites tend to be filled with helpful information.

If that doesn't get you enough to help with the design, Google beam expander.